# What is a good way to filter xUnit tests in .NET?

Tags: .net, xunit.net

We are trying to set up filtering for our xUnit tests in our current solution that is built in the .NET framework (4.6). Most resources suggest to use filtering via the dotnet command but that is only for .NET Core. Is there a good way to do this without the dotnet command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xunit.runner.console seems to work but it's deprecated so we didn't want to use it. We ended up using [vstest.console.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/vstest-console-options?view=vs-2019).

Answer (score 0):

`xunit.runner.console` has filtering options. It's [downloadable from nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/xunit.runner.console/).